# SSRS Using Dataset Field value in Query expression

Tags: reporting-services

I use SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services.Is it possible to use Dataset field value in query expression when query type is text?

Comment: Maybe you can explain more about what you are trying to achieve? What result are you trying to get by doing that?

Comment: From what I understand of your question yes, but we'll need more detail on what exactly you're struggling with